# reordering form parameters for file upload in sails.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, sails.js

I am unable to receiver parameters which are after the file upload parameter. This is skipper issue which is given in its documentation. It was suggested to reorder the parameters on clicking the submit button , before going to server. Can anyone kindly tell me how to reorder all the parameters in the form , I have searched for my answer and unable to get the desired results.

Ejs File (Client Side)

```
<h2>
    Enter  Details
</h2>
<br>
<div class="container">
    <form  action ="/upload" id="form" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        Name:<input type="text" id='name' name='name' placeholder="Enter Name"/>
        File:<input type="file" name="uploadFile" />
        <a onclick="clearFileInputField('uploadFile')" href="javascript:noAction();">
            Clear
        </a>
        <br>
        Address:<input type="text" id='address' name='address'/>
        mobile:<input type="string" id='mobile' name='mobile'/>
        pincode:<input type="string" id='pincode' name='pincode'/>
        <button type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-success" >
            Submit
        </button>
    </form>
    </p>
    <script>
        function clearFileInputField(tagId) {
        document.getElementById(tagId).innerHTML =
        document.getElementById(tagId).innerHTML;
        }
    </script>
</div>
```

File Controller (Server Side)

```
/**
 * FileController
 *
 * @description :: Server-side logic for managing files
 * @help        :: See http://sailsjs.org/#!/documentation/concepts/Controllers
 */

module.exports = {
    upload: function(req,res){
        console.log(req.body);
        var uploadFile = req.file('uploadFile');
        uploadFile.upload(function onUploadComplete (err, files) {              
        //  Files will be uploaded to .tmp/uploads

            if (err) return res.serverError(err);                               
            //  IF ERROR Return and send 500 error with error

            res.json({status:200,file:files});
        });
    }

};
```

Output:
  { name: 'Test' }

Desired Output:
{ name: 'test',
  address: 'address',
  mobile: '1234567891',
  pincode: '21341' }

Comment: If question is not proper, please suggest changes to get response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by using pseudo forms. Pseudo forms can be made by using simple javascript formData.

Files were not included in formData. They were uploaded asynchronously using AJAX calls to servers.